# MYSQL select table by desc order limiting from last 10 rows

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the rows which basically contains the comments of a, I want to use pagination, and trying to get the latest 10 comments in the order of old to new, so when I scroll up my page I am planning to load the next 10 rows. I am able to limit the rows but not able to achieve the ASC order, if I try ORDER BY comment_id ASC Limit 0,10 I am getting the first 10 rows.

Below is what I am using now

```
SELECT * 
    FROM comments 
WHERE chat_id = 1
ORDER BY id comment_id ASC
   LIMIT 0,10
```

This shows the first 10 rows though, not the last 10.

I Want the last 10 rows (Which yes, DESC does this) However I want them to be returned in ASCENDING order.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery here to get the final reverse ordering you want:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM comments 
    WHERE chat_id = 1
    ORDER BY comment_id DESC  -- last 10 rows
    LIMIT 10
) t
ORDER BY comment_id;          -- in ascending order
```

Comment: Thanks I tried and code worked, is there any other way other than subquery method. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Subbu Are you using MySQL 8+?  We could use `ROW_NUMBER` here, but it would still require a subquery.

Comment: am not using MySQL 8, but I've been searching the internet for such a cosdifiton, cause we use this scenario is daily life in social media chats, where we scroll up and view old comments in desc order, so I was wondering if even those apps need to use sub query.

Comment: I am concerned about sub-query because when I use EXPLAIN I see an additional 10 rows for the sub-query, I've spent much time to optimise the tables and add relevant index to make the query faster, yet this subquery would be a mess on the longer run right?

Comment: There is no avoiding a subquery AFAIK. But, there are ways you an optimize the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT * FROM yourTableName WHERE yourCondition ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
)Var1
   ORDER BY id ASC;
```